# How Deny many users logging with same user in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, frameworks

i have problem with my app " multi user  can logging same user i need to prevent this problem i hope to help me
my code :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
    $posts = $this->input->post();
    $name  = $this->input->post('name');
    $pass  = $this->input->post('pass');   

    if(isset($posts['submit']))
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name ', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'pass ', 'trim|required');    

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $this->load->model("users_model");
            $res = $this->users_model->auth($name,$pass); 
            if(!empty($res))
            {
                foreach($res as $r)
                { 
                    if($r->active == 0)
                    {
                        $err = '<h4 class="alert alert-danger"> error loggin
```

Comment: What do you mean ... You want to prevent one user logging from multiple device..

Comment: the easiest way to do this is to have a login_status in your users table in the database, set it to 1 if the user already logged in and check the login_status depending on users credential on every login

Comment: for example : username: john and pass = 123123123
when one user logged this user can't another log same user that what i mean

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that a user doesnt login twice you could store the sessions in the [database](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver) and then check on login if the user is logged in. If so, remove the old user and allow login or maybe show a confirm message whether to terminate the remaining session or not. What i recommend is to make the session automatically [expire](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to better write the separate controller for login.Your login controller should like this below,

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Controllername extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model("users_model");

        if(!empty($this->session->userdata('userid');))
        {
            /*if any try to login again if they already logged in make them to redirect to 
               any other page you want*/
        }
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name ', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'pass ', 'trim|required');

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {

            $res = $this->users_model->auth($name,$pass); 
            if(!empty($res))
            {
                //if the userdata matches then set the session while login

                $this->session->set_userdata('userid', $res[0]->userid );

               //after login redirect the user to where you want

            } 

         }
    }

}
```

By checking the session as not empty it prevent the user to login again.Whenever user try to login it checks for the session is empty or not in constructor.If the session is not there then it normally goes to login function.If the session is already set then it redirects to any other page you want.